# jQuery class selector not selecting after class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, button, jquery-selectors

Im using Javascript to build a button click and puzzle adventure game. The game will allow a series of button commands. When the "go" command is clicked, the buttons change to different exits, and the class is changed to exit, like so:

```
function setExitButtons(){
    clearButtons();
    for (var i = 0; i < player.currentRoom.exits.length; i++) {
            var buttoni = button[i];
            buttoni.className = "exit";
            buttoni.innerHTML = player.currentRoom.exits[i].name;
            $(buttoni).show();
    }

}
```

Where clearButtons hides all of the buttons so only the correct ones show, and button[] is the nodelist for the buttons.

The class does change when this function is called.

I then have another jquery function with a class selector, like so:

```
$(".exit").click(function(){
          //roomchangefunction
});
```

The .exit function is not activated when the button with exit class is clicked. I have a document ready function encompassing the whole part. Thoughts?

Comment: You're adding the class name after the page has loaded so  need to use `.on()` with delegated events. It's been answered so many times, it doesn't need to be on here again.

Comment: the button (the condition for the event) doesn't exist at the time the `.click` handler is added. You need to use `.on` on a parent element that always exists so that the event can bubble up and be caught there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This only runs once, when the document loads:

```
$(".exit").click(function(){
    //roomchangefunction
});
```

At that time, there are no matching elements for `.exit`.  So no click handlers are assigned.  After that, this never runs again.

Since the elements are dynamically changing, I recommend binding a click handler to a common parent element [using `.on()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.exit', function () {
    //roomchangefunction
});
```

The difference is that the click event is actually assigned to a common parent (in this case `document`, though any common parent element will work such as a `div` which always contains the `.exit` elements).  When an element is clicked, the "click" event occurs on that element and all the way up the DOM.  So this handler would be invoked.  The second argument is a filter, so it looks for elements which match that filter when invoking the handler function.

That way the filter for `.exit` happens when the element is clicked, rather than when the document is loaded, so that elements which are dynamically changed during the life of the document are still handled.

Comment: Is there a way to reference which button with exit class was clicked? Originally I used $(this) but now that references the document.

Comment: @kahjav: Are you sure that references `document`?  Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/uTP9R/  `this` is referencing the element which originated the click event, not the element which has the handler.

Comment: It wasn't referencing the button, but I just used event.target and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the class name after the page has loaded so need to use .on() with delegated events.  Basically it means, the event is bound to the parent (in this case `document`), but affects the designated children (in this case `.exit`).

```
$(document).on('click', '.exit', function(){
          //roomchangefunction
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.on()` like so:

```
$(".exit").on("click", function(){
          //roomchangefunction
});
```

Comment: This suffers the same problem, `.exit` doesn't exist when the handler is assigned.

Comment: Oh yes, thx I see,..  `$(document).on('click', '.exit', function () {`. You are right.  :)